How can I adjust this recipe to firm up a cake sponge?
I have baked this chocolate cake a number of times now, and family and friends will vouch that it is one of the best chocolate cakes they have eaten.
However, the cake is so moist and delicate, that even after being left to cool on a rack it has a tendency to break in the middle. I have now resorted to using my pizza peel to lift it! Reading comments online by others who have made it, I am not alone in this.
Are there any tweaks I can make to this recipe just to firm it up a notch, without losing the texture and lightness? I was thinking of reducing the stout by a small amount to reduce the moisture content, but am concerned that the cake will end up dry.

Ingredients:

1 ½ cups flour
1 cup dutch processed cocoa powder
1 teaspoon salt
1½ teaspoons baking soda
½ teaspoon baking powder
1½ cups stout
1 tablespoon vanilla extract
1 tablespoon espresso powder
1 cup butter
1½ cups sugar
3 eggs
½ cup mayonnaise
4 oz dark chocolate, chopped

Full recipe from Tasty (The Best Chocolate Cake)

if it does end up dry, you can do what  the professionals do, and drizzle on some sugar syrup or other liquid over the cut layers to add some moisture back in

You could increase the flour, decrease the stout, even adjust the eggs or butter to subtly firm it up. However, any and all of this /will/ have a result on the final texture. Without experimenting with this exact recipe, there is simply no way of telling which result (if any) will be acceptable to you. Unfortunately, you can't have a light cake and have it dense too.
